# Using WiX to target public documents folder in Windows XP and Vista

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I've used `WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS`, as described in [OSInfo custom actions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/osinfo.html), to install a file in a `Public Documents` folder in `Windows 7, 8, and 10` where, I've tested that, the file is installed at `C:\users\Public\Documents`. I don't have access to `XP` or `Vista`. **Question**: Where on the target systems `XP` or `Vista` the `WiX` installer will install the file if I'm using the same code? **Note**: I'm using WiX 3.11 RC but this probably should not matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows XP it will be `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents`.

For Windows Vista it should be same as for Windows 7: `C:\Users\Public\Documents`.

You can use [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/osinfo.html) and [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744) to find locations of the other Special Folders.

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents` -- note that XP path is localized, e. g. on a german system it would be `C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Dokumente`. That changed with Vista, where physical path is no longer localized, Explorer just *displays* it localized.